# HTML dropdown doesn't line up with rest of table row

Tags: html, css, angular, forms

I got a table with input fields and one select field, but the select field doesn't line up with the rest of the row. If I use an input field instead, it works normally.
It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdYTu.png), and the code for that table data element like this:

```
<td formGroupName="product" style="width: 5%; vertical-align: middle;">
        <select formControlName="unit" id="unit" style="width: 100%">
          <option *ngFor="let unit of units" [value]="unit.value"  matTooltip="Please select the unit of the ordered product.">
            {{unit.view}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
```

How can I make the select fit in? It doesn't have anything to do with the width I think, as it still was too much on the left when I chose a bigger width.

Comment: why vertical align middle added?

Comment: Otherwise the fields and buttons wouldn't be in line. The other <td>s have it too. If i remove it from the select, it will not only be off horizontally but also vertically.